# People are doing worst/nothing editing to gain rep then misusing those ids

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I am reviewing the question which came for edit, and almost every day I see a new id with an edit spree. A user x who has not given any answer or asked any question but has a rep of 500+ only from editing.
They are not helping SO in any way but only gaining rep even by removing a space, making a character big or similar edits which won't improve a question.
It's not the first time but from months I'm seeing this. I searched and found these 2 questions with the same point:

1. [Asked in 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258327/handling-floods-of-too-minor-suggested-edits)
2. [Asked in 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326682/raising-rep-by-flooding-the-suggested-edit-queue)

And by reading both, what I got is **flag those** edits so a mod can contact them as said by Undo (Mod on so). But nowadays what I can see is people are making fake ids to get rep and then doing upvotes (for their profile rep) and downvote (to take revenge). So they don't care if a mod contacts/bans them as they will start doing this by a new id. And well I'm seeing new id's almost every day so it's not possible for mods even to contact each and every fake id.

For this, I have read that reviewers will help but as mentioned in the question itself, there are **robo reviewers** too and by this those user will be safe.

So my question is **Can't we create something or put limitation on this??**

This topic is active from 2014 and still we are helpless. People are getting worth of rep and taking revenge and what we can do is _reject their wrong edits while other reviewers will approve!!

I hope atleast this will make a little bit of sense to SO mods or admins and that they will create/make something (Rule/abandon/limit) for those people.

**UPDATED**
See robo reviewer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13243011)
And how low rep guy(76 rep) can review edits, [how](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13242611)?? And loos at this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6551577/alex-m) and this [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13304824) i know i will reject but other people will approve, what to do :(

**Magic**
No rep by answer but all rep with edit only and question with downvotes?? what to do with [them](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3898985/amarendra-kumar?tab=profile) [:(](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6198301/yaseen?tab=profile)

Even [he](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5536063/pramod-gharu?tab=profile) gave only 3 answer and 500+ rep.

Comment: My favorite edits to make: https://github.com/cirosantilli/stack-overflow-vote-fraud-script/blob/796bbfd8a0b1908ecff1b70b927d10a0809377f1/puppets.md#trivial-edits Hopefully new edit limit breaks them.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, people create fake accounts and use them to suggest edits to farm reputation to the point where they can vote. It's a known sock puppet tactic and we deal with it regularly.

These accounts show up just as strongly in our vote fraud tools as sock puppet accounts that gained reputation via questions and answers, and we deal with them just as quickly. In fact, it's easier for us to delete these accounts because they have no content to their name.

I should note that sock puppet accounts which build their reputation only via suggested edits are pretty rare compared to the standard approach of posting a couple of answers or questions and getting the main account to vote for them. It takes a lot more effort to spam suggested edits than to have one or two answers accepted, and sock puppet operators are pretty lazy people.

Even more rare are sock puppet accounts that are used to attack others with downvotes. In almost all cases, the primary focus of the sock puppet operator is to boost the reputation of their main account and / or help them avoid a question ban. Rarely are these accounts used for anything other than helping the main account, and if we do find that someone used a fake account to attack another person we come down on them like a ton of bricks.

To your question asking what's to stop people from doing this? Well, suspension of the main account works as a pretty good deterrent. No point in having a sock puppet if your main account can't benefit. For more persistent puppet operators, certain types of account deletion [now lock out the reuse of login credentials](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277230/automatically-suspend-accounts-recreated-after-a-moderator-deleted-the-original/278803#278803), adding friction to the account creation process. These deletions also start building a location-based block against the creation of new accounts, which seems to stop all but the most persistent trolls and puppet operators.

For the rest, I [recently asked about what else Stack Overflow could do to prevent sock puppet account creation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324220/should-stack-overflow-be-more-restrictive-about-new-user-registrations), but that discussion didn't really bring up any obvious solutions (and went in a different direction than I'd intended).

Comment: Have you thought of associating the user's IP address (or perhaps using a cookie with IP+geolocation+other_stuff) to the new account? Or simply associating this when a user logs in? This field could perhaps never be shown to the user, but it would help you knowing if the user is "mistakenly" using the same device for 2 different accounts and tracking down these sock puppet accounts. Ultimately the user could be denied to create a new account even if he uses VPNs/proxies due to his records. I haven't found this suggestion yet in that other question, sorry if I am repeating something...

Comment: @CPHPython - I won't talk specifics, but you can assume that tracking users by IP is something that SO has thought about quite a bit. There are issues with purely IP-based identification of users: many public IPs in use by people accessing this site have hundreds of users associated with them, and then there are the dynamic IPs at ISPs.

Comment: What is stopping a revengeful user from creating lots of accounts, then using these to upvote another user's (the victim) account? In order to make it seem like the other unsuspecting user is using these accounts to gain reputation. At the end a completely innocent user may get a ban.

Comment: I am considering dynamic IPs @BradLarson. The IPs the user "get" would just serve to make a record in his account. If he gets always the same couple of IPs and a new account is created, you may potentially have a red flag there. If he gets hundreds of different IPs, you can track down other accounts with those same IPs. And if you associate these to geolocation (or other more detailed data about their devices) and do a little bit of data mining, I think the results would be surprising.

Comment: @NuriTasdemir - All suspensions are issued by moderators, not the system. We personally review the accounts involved, and it would be pretty obvious to us that accounts like this weren't associated with the target. I can't think of any case where someone has attempted this. At worst, we've seen some individual accounts who've serially upvoted another account, hoping to get them in trouble, but it was clear what was going on. If there's any doubt, we can call in SE to simply invalidate the votes, and do nothing else.

Comment: @BradLarson I provided a little bit more detail on the idea in an [answer below](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331647/6225838).

Comment: @BradLarson thank you for your time and lines. Yes its better to ban their main rather then sock. But i think you totally forget about Robo reviewer.. any idea to stop them??

Comment: @BradLarson: The easy scenario is: silly question and irrelevant improvement. What if the sock puppet acount improves the answer?
No point it should be banned for the unfair practice, but what about the review of the edit? Should be accepted when it is an actual  improvement or rejected to discourage this misbehaviour?

Answer (score 17):

There is a lot of intolerance being displayed lately about the way SO users earn rep.  Not a good thing, the usual reason behind intolerance is a lack of empathy.

It might help to put this into perspective a bit.  500 rep does *not* make anybody reputable.  It might seem like a big number but SO users routinely earn this in 2 or 3 days.  Some of them haven't even shown up for months.  Earning it by editing is certainly the most painful way to get any.  Jeez marie, it takes *250* approved edits.  Writing as many post easily earns ten times more.

Sure, those edits no doubt look "small".  It is an inevitable side-effect of reviewers almost always rejecting large edits, no matter how good they are.  Small edits are the inevitable result.  The review system isn't great, it would probably work much better if the reviewers always knew something about the [tags] on the question.  It is not likely that it is going to be changed anytime soon, SE works on very different priorities lately.

I'm not really sure why SO users spend so much time on something with so very little gain.  I suspect it is done by programmers that have no real way to earn rep any other way.  Getting an answer upvoted isn't that easy, a reasonable amount of competence in the subject matter is necessary and that's often unavailable.  Good odds they want to have some rep in the bank so they can spend it on a bounty.  The only consistent way to get a lot of views and no close-votes.

A lack of community-feel is often behind a lack of empathy.  The "regulars" don't show up anymore, everybody is a stranger.  It is up to the next generation of SO users to keep the site going.  Sniping at each other about perceived improper rep gain is never going to rebuild a community.

Comment: Thanx for your lines. Yes to get uv on real answer is damn tough. I have been through where it takes a lot time/hardwork to create fiddle and give solution to user but then he got disappeared without giving any votes. :( And that time you see wrong answer is getting uv..flag and then robo reviewer will reject saying answer is answer.. but what we need is solution, yes solution.

Comment: 250 serious edits are hard work. 250 edits that **randomly boldface** things or put `product names` in code markdown are easy. Some will get rejected, but a lot will fall through. The robo-reviewers are a large part of the problem. Solve that, and we get editors who are only rewarded for decent edits. +2 for a good edit is perfectly OK with me; +2 for **randomly** `adding` _markdown_ is not.

Comment: The questioner is inconsequential, he's just one person with two votes.  You earn rep from the *thousands* of other programmers that read the Q+A over the years.  If you chase the insta-rep from the usual ~15 SO users that read the Q+A in the first few hours then you want to make sure to keep them friendly and entertained.  As I said, sniping accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Those edits are annoying me no end too. Perhaps SO should introduce edit-review audits that add random markup.

Comment: @piet.t I [proposed that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272518/generate-new-types-of-audits-for-the-suggested-edits-queue), and other audits, two years ago. It's never been actioned though.

Comment: If you hate it that much then just reject the edit.  Expecting somebody else to do it for you, well, how often does that ever turn out well.  About as well as complaining about it, usually.  Do focus a bit on the big picture, no system has a 0% failure rate.  Q+A in particular isn't anywhere near to that.

Comment: @HansPassant He does reject these edits. So do I, often with a custom reject reason so that the editor will learn what is wrong - and can do better in their next edit. But it's an uphill battle - we can at most reject 20 of them each day (and risk vengeance downvotes in the process).  IMO, the core of the problem is the robo-reviewing. I've suggested better audits as a possible solution. I'll be glad to hear other solutions.

Comment: @S.L.Barth yes i have faced revenge dv on those answer which i gave year ago.. :( and if i will reject, no worry robo reviewer is there :(

Comment: 500 rep in 2 or 3 days? Try living in the java tag. I'd wager that half my rep on SO comes from answering questions that shouldn't have even been asked. I only even reached 100 rep because I rocked an answer on Sci-fi. I would love to reach 500 rep, since then I could review stuff and actually be useful to the community at large, but I fully expect that to take several months of answering questions I should actually flag.

Comment: So don't answer questions that shouldn't have been asked, @Jeutnarg. Folks get this idea that they should "grind" for rep, and... It becomes a grind, and you get this petty jealousness that Hans talks about. Write for yourself, then for the asker, then for your peers... Never for the rep. The rep is just a way of keeping track on how you're doing with the real stuff.

Answer (score 12):

This has recently (July 13, 2016) been addressed.

From  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/168333 :

> at-most 20 pending suggested edits per editor on beta sites
>   at-most 5 pending suggested edits per editor on graduated sites

So, it's no longer possible to flood the edit queue with hundreds of edits. In fact, it's not possible to suggest an edit if there are 200 or more edits pending.

There still is a problem with robo-approvers; reviewers who carelessly approve every edit suggestion they encounter. This needs to be adressed more effectively.

But it has become a little harder to raise lots of rep from sloppy edits.

If people use fake ID's to upvote their own posts, that is voting fraud. There are systems in place to detect this, and users who get caught are suspended.

Since votes are anonymous, it is impossible for us to know for certain if someone committed voting fraud; only the SO developers can see that (not even the moderators!)
However, if you have sufficient indications that a user may be committing voting fraud, flag one of their posts for moderator attention and present what evidence you have. Do make sure that there is enough evidence, or at least enough hints, that someone is committing voting fraud.

Comment: yes robo reviewers :( but i don't think that will be effective much as i can see user are getting 10 to 20rep in day and doing it from so many days..what about them?

Comment: Not much we can do about throwaway accounts that only exist to raise rep, I'm afraid. Flag them, and hope that the moderators will see. You can ease the burden on the moderators a little, by helping out in the review queues. Every Low Quality post that is reviewed by the community, is one less for the ♦ moderators.

Comment: @S. L. Barth, not to be rude but seriously i hate flag system as in my a lot flag they got declined as the _did not find any evidence_ as user deleted answer(in my case) or they can contact n no of user but m sure it won't effective much as there are other issues too which mod have to handle.I am just asking for strict rules/things so we can stop those rep-hogs.

Comment: @Leothelion One thing that has been suggested was: not giving rep for edits. Unfortunately I can't find it back. IIRC it was heavily downvoted back then. These days, I would upvote it. From my real account and from all my fake accou... er, I mean, I would upvote it. :-P

Answer (score 2):

There are not enough ♦ moderators to handle the sheer amount of useless suggested edits; that's why we have the review queues. As for the robo-reviewers, there's some good news about that. ♦ moderators have been starting to hand out review suspensions for people who are approving useless edits: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330361/4751173) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261812/4751173) [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327052/4751173). Even to the point where they make [mistakes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330555/4751173) doing it :)

If people use sock puppets to upvote their own answers, that will be detected by the voting fraud detection algorithm and the votes will be reversed.

Comment: the banned user asked this question and then reviewer came on front but what if another user did not ask then how can we mark who is robo reviewer?

Comment: @about voting fraud, well if m not wrong i can easily be safe by that algo as ex. Mr x(new id) will give upvote to all good answer but not the only one for whom he create and mr x will balance the factor that he won't give too many uv to his id only, simple then what we can do?

Comment: The second link is two years old... mods seem to be waging an uphill battle against robo-reviewers too.

Answer (score -1):

I am focusing more on [Brad Larson's input](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331640/6225838) to answer the problem:

> IP-based restrictions are already used, but they're tricky to get right. Many, many **public-facing IP addresses have dozens to hundreds of Stack Overflow users** associated with them. That makes it difficult to associate a new fake account with the existing original, even if they are on the same IP. However, I have started tagging question-ban evasion accounts as trolls when deleting them in order to block near-future posts from that location. It has been effective at stopping more persistent ban evaders, but I worry about people getting hit in the crossfire with that. There might be a way to leverage more intelligence here.

So IP-based only identification may not be enough for some users because they may be using public IP addresses.

What about the rest of them? How many are those that normally have the same IP and suddenly have two or more accounts? Is this data not useful, specially if one account directly influences the other(s)?

I am not focusing on IP-based restrictions, since that's probably outdated due to how cheap is to acquire/use a new device or proxies/VPNs and connect to the internet... I am talking about (IP+geolocation+browser_data+device_data)-account-based tracking and [data mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining).

> **Moderators commonly trace people based on patterns of how they create email addresses**, but these patterns don't seem easy for a machine to pick out. There are the obvious cases (an account using puppetoperator1@gmail.com voting for an account using puppetoperator2@gmail.com), but again those might only be obvious to a human looking at them.

Firstly, this seems to be a little beyond moderators responsibilities (and perhaps skills).

Secondly, email addresses tracking is a very limited method to track a person.

Thirdly, there could be a group of people who specifically dedicate their time to analyze where users create accounts, how often and from which devices they create them, and how often they interact with other accounts with similar contexts (location and browser&devices specs). This is almost pure data mining and statistical analysis. If you imagine a more detailed and account-oriented Google Analytics for StackExchange, that would be it.

I am not even suggesting to share the data you may acquire by doing this with the users, this initially could be solely focused on providing information to Admins. It would give StackExchange real hard data to measure and analyze in order to draw conclusions from them (probably this would help even more in marketing than account-closing purposes).